# How to connect to any database using J2ME?

Tags: java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JDBC support on J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794770/jdbc-support-on-j2me)

I am not getting it. Can any one help me?

Comment: no one has magic ball to see into your brain and decipher what you _really_ wanted to know.

Comment: i want to have database connection with j2me program

Comment: You can't find any better tutorial on JDBC than [JDBC Tutorial Trail from Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)

Comment: i want to have the connection in j2me and the syntax of java and j2me is different ... and its like to have connection to mobile database..... i am going to run this application in mobile ... so is ther any way tol stored the database in mobile or der ther is any mobile database ... if it is an standalone applicaion in mobile no network connectivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794770/jdbc-support-on-j2me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you are trying to do is accessing a remote database from your Mobile device (j2me) using JDBC or similar tool.
Unfortunately, if you use CLDC then there is no tool for connecting to database using JDBC like tool, you need to do it manually i.e you need to send customized data like username, password from the MIDlet to Servlet and then the servlet deals with the database. Here is a [sample](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html)

It is not necessary to use Servlet (i.e Java) in server side, you can use any other server-side language like PHP etc.